# how to add, remove the ListAdapter Items in android?

Tags: android

I know The ListAdpater extends a recyclerview adapter. And for initializing items, I use submitList method. the parameter in submitList method is defined like this, typed list.

```
    public void submitList(@Nullable List<T> list) {
        mDiffer.submitList(list);
    }
```

I can't remove or add items. So I tried using arraylist variable for adding and removing, and casted it to List. But I'm not sure this is the good way...
Because arraylist is not good to add or remove items. Is there other way?

Comment: You can take care of these actions with `DiffUtil` .. [Here is nice article](https://medium.com/simform-engineering/listadapter-a-recyclerview-adapter-extension-5359d13bd879) you can checkout on `ListAdapter`.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share the answer.

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy just call submitList

Answer (score 5):

Delete item from ListAdapter. (Kotlin)

```
fun removeItem(position: Int){
       val currentList =  adapter.currentList.toMutableList()
        currentList.removeAt(position)
        adapter.submitList(currentList)

    }
```

Tested and working fine.

Comment: If we remove an item from any position (not the last) and then remove the last item, we get a null pointer exception.
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Answer (score 0):

Just call submitList with a new list, the diffutil will take care of the old list and the new list.
If you add or remove something, add to your original list or remove an item from your list and then call submitList.

you can call use adapter.currentList to get your current list, or just use a viewModel to hold your list items.

Answer (score 0):

> MyAdapter

```
class FavoritesAdapter(
private val listeners: OnFavoriteDetailPage,
private val itemClick: (title: String, price: String) -> Unit) :ListAdapter<Favorites, FavoritesAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>(ListComparator()) {
//bind the recycler list items

inner class RecyclerViewHolder(val binding: FavoriteListBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bind(list: Favorites) {
        binding.deal.text = "Deal " + list.id.toString()
        binding.price.text = "Ghc " + list.price
        binding.pizzaSize.text = list.size.toString()
        binding.posterBanner.load(list.imgUrl)
    }
}

inflate the List
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
    return RecyclerViewHolder(
        FavoriteListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    )
}

//bind the model list the recycler list
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val getItemPosition = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(getItemPosition)
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(getItemPosition.imgUrl)
        .into(holder.binding.posterBanner)
    holder.binding.addCart.setOnClickListener {
        itemClick("Deal ${getItemPosition.id}", getItemPosition.price)
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        listeners.viewDetail(getItemPosition)
    }

    holder.binding.favoriteHeart.setOnClickListener {
        listeners.onItemRemoveClick(getItemPosition.id)
    }
}


class ListComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Favorites>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Favorites, newItem: Favorites): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Favorites, newItem: Favorites): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }
}

interface OnFavoriteDetailPage {
    fun viewDetail(favorites: Favorites)
    fun onItemRemoveClick(position: Int)
}
```

}

> Inside my fragment

```
 override fun onItemRemoveClick(position: Int) {
    val currentList = recyclerAdapter.currentList.toMutableList()
    currentList.removeAt(position)
    recyclerAdapter.submitList(currentList)
}
```

**Everythings works fine but mine delete from the bottom of the list instead of the current postion. What could be the problem?**